# Using "A cold yesterday" as noun phrase

Tags: phrases, parts-of-speech

In this [Google Books search for "a cold yesterday"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20cold%20yesterday%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), I found "Johnny had **a cold yesterday**."

Is this usage correct? Can we use "quality-adjective + adverbial noun" to make "noun group"?

Answer (score 26):

*Cold yesterday* is not a noun phrase in the examples in the link. *Cold* refers to an illness, and *yesterday* refers to the time he had the illness and is not part of the noun phrase. The sentence is correct and can also be written as *Yesterday, Johnny had a cold*.

Comment: Colds refer to reduced body temperature, which are often caused by certain illnesses. This is in contrast to fevers which are elevated body temperature, often caused by other illnesses.

Comment: @jaxad0127 Do you have a reference for that? I would assume that "a cold" refers to the constellation of viral infection upper respiratory symptoms commonly called the ["common cold"](http://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/cold-guide/common_cold_causes), which can include low-grade fever.

Comment: Double checking the source I checked earlier, it can be both. Great....

Comment: @jaxad0127: Would you care to share that source? The [dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cold) I [checked](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold) only list the "common cold" meaning. (Don't confuse *a cold*, which means the viral illness that 1006a was talking about, with *cold* or *the cold*, which means low temperature in general.)

Comment: So that there be no doubt, let me state that as a native speaker, I'm agreeing that "a cold" refers to an illness that people commonly think they are more prone to get when they are exposed to cold temperatures, and that resulting (feverish) high temperatures can be a part of the experience of having "a cold".  This is the reality of common usage, despite whether the dictionaries go into that much detail.

Comment: In @jasper's re-written sentence, *yeterday* is an interjection. In the original sentence, it could be considered an adverbial phrase, describing the verb *had*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but that's not what's being done here.

"Cold" here is used as a noun, referring to an illness where the person has a runny nose, watery eyes, and sneezes. So "Johnny had a cold" means that the person named Johnny had the illness which is called a "cold". "Yesterday" is an adverb saying when he had it: he had it yesterday.

That said, there is a very similar construction that might confuse you. It is common to say things like, "We had a cold winter", meaning that the winter was cold. In this case "winter" is the noun and "cold" is an adjective modifying "winter".

Similarly, someone might say, "We had a very busy Monday": Monday is the noun, busy is an adjective. "Yesterday" can be used as a noun, as in, "Yesterday was my birthday". I've never heard someone say, "We had a busy yesterday", it's not something fluent speakers say, but if I heard someone say that I'd assume they meant "yesterday" as a noun and "busy" as the adjective.

Comment: To add to this, we'd normally say "We had a busy day, yesterday" rather than "We had a busy yesterday".

Comment: I could also see "a cold yesterday" being used as a poetic phrase for "a cold day long ago".

Comment: @ThePhoton Exactly. If someone said, "We had a busy yesterday", I'd understand what he meant. But it's not the way most people would say it.